# Can you use DBeaver without connecting to a database?

Tags: dbeaver

I would like to develop a ER diagram using DBeaver (Eclipse plugin) for a database that doesn't yet exist. Also, the database server doesn't exist.

Can DBeaver be used to develop a ER diagram without connecting to an existing database server? I can only find documentation for working with an existing database or connecting to an existing database server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, sorry.
DBeaver tools are always associated with the current connection.
For example, in the ERD when adding tables, DBeaver often sends requests to the database of foreign keys.
You can use standard sample SQLite database in DBeaver for experiments.